# Print and Preferences Dialog Boxes Too Large

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

Having a strange issue that I've never come across before, and although some existing forum questions seem to have similar problems, I have yet to find an answer that satisfies the issue.

A user came to me saying that their Adobe Acrobat Reader won't let them print - the dialog box looks like this:
[image: Too Large to Print]

As you can see, pretty much impossible to get to any of the options, and they're all crossed out for some reason. There is a vertical scrollbar, but no horizontal one.

One explanation I found said that there may be something wrong in Windows itself, so I ran `sfc \scannow` but it came up with no errors. I also ran Windows Update, CCleaner, Disk Cleanup...all the usual stuff just to see if I could find something. I also uninstalled Adobe Reader XI and installed Adobe Reader DC and had the exact same issue. The "Preferences" dialog box also looks like this.

The only thing that I've been able to do that made any difference at all is to re-install an existing system (i.e. once Adobe Reader DC is installed, run the installer again anyway), and it ends up looking like this:

[image: Blank buttons]

I've seen several posts regarding the default Windows fonts, but none have actually helped - the fonts appear the same as on another Win7 x64 computer, and I don't think that would explain why the window itself is so huge anyway.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated! I have no idea what could cause this!

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution, just copy/paste all fonts from C:\Windows\Fonts of a PC working fine to the bug one, and it works.

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already confirmed that all of the default Windows fonts were present on that computer - and I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Adobe Reader, which should also have brought along any fonts it needed. I tried this solution as well, and also a solution I had seen for using a Windows disk to repair a Windows installation, which should restore all fonts.No luck at all. I ended up reformatting the computer. Thanks for your input, though!

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone, here what I did.

I tried copying all the fonts from a working computer to the bugged one, didn't work at first.

I deleted all the fonts on the faulty computer (it won't let you delete the system protected one, that's fine) and I reinstall all the fonts from the working computer. Tried Adobe Reader again and it works.